# Different emoji set on telegram message

Tags: python, android, telegram, emoji

I'm developing a telegram bot, written on Python. Messages are sent using the official Telegram API. It is a photo with a caption, so I use the following endpoint: `https://api.telegram.org/{{bot_token}}/sendPhoto`

The problem is the following one:

Once it is sent an I see this message on my Android phone (Realme X2 Pro, right screenshot), it seems that from an arbitrary length of the message the emoji set changes from Apple to Google (according to how basketball emojis are shown here: https://emojipedia.org/basketball/). But, if I see this message on an iPhone (left screenshot), the message is shown perfectly.

[image: iOS and Android screenshots]

This is the code I'm using to send a pic with its caption:

```
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/{{bot_token}}/sendPhoto'
files = {'photo': open('final.jpg', 'rb')}
payload = dict(chat_id={{bot_id}}, caption=mensaje, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=files)
```

Do anyone knows if it is something I'm doing wrong?

### EDIT

I've been testing with a message just of emojis and what I get is: the first 50 emojis are shown with the Apple set; from 51th, it looks like Google set. Check it:

[image]

This is the code I've used for this test:

```
money = u'\U0001F4B0'
message = ""
for i in range(200):
    message += money
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/{{bot_token}}/sendMessage'
payload = dict(chat_id={{bot_id}}, text=message)
res = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide code that generates value of `mensaje` variable (with emojis)? Looks like you are generating it using different methods.

Comment: Check my edit @wowkin2

Comment: Really weird behavior.

Comment: Same issue here, the message shows fine on IOS/MacOS devies, but on android, they change.